# R grepl: whole word matching not working for punctuation marks

Tags: r, regex, grepl

`text = 'this is ; an example'`

Language is R. I'd like to understand why:

`grepl("\\<is\\>",text)`

returns `TRUE`

while

`grepl("\\<;\\>",text)`

returns `FALSE`

Note that setting the `perl` argument to `TRUE` or `FALSE` doesn't make any difference. I know that `grepl(";",text)` works, my question is why doesn't it work anymore when we add word boundaries.

Comment: I posted an answer since the common [What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/) post does not cover TRE library and these patterns in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\<` is a leading word boundary and the `\>` is a trailing word boundary. So, the char after `\<` must be a word char, and the char before `\>` should be a word char.

The `;` is not a word char. The `\<;\>` will never match any string as the `\<;` means *match a `;` that is preceded with a leading word boundary* and `;\>` means *match a `;` that is followed with a trailing word boundary*, i.e. requires a `;` to be a word char, which is false.

Comment: thanks, this is good to know. Are all punctuation marks not word chars?

Comment: All punctuation symbols are not word chars, 100% true. Note that word chars are: letters, digits and `_`. [`"\\<Abc\\>"` won't match `Abc` in `_Abc_`](https://ideone.com/6hFmoC)